# Why forEach is not listed as one of the JS Loops?

Tags: javascript, html

As, I was checking on different kinds of loops in JavaScript, in both of the sites, it says 5 loops:

1. While
2. Do-While
3. For
4. For-in
5. For-of

**References:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Now, I know that there is a `forEach` loop, but why is it not listed in both of the above sites (Mozzilla mdn/ W3Schools)? Have they missed out or what's the matter?

**Sample Code for ForEach:**

```js
var arr = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
arr.forEach(item=>console.log(item));
```

Also, did I miss out any loop, please add! or comment.

Comment: Because `forEach` isn't a loop, it's a function property of arrays and some array-like objects.

Comment: It also doesn't list `.map()`, `.find()`, `.reduce()`, `.some()`, and many more. They are functions that perform iteration, but the term "loop" is generally used to describe syntactic features for iteration.

Comment: It's not a loop. It's a method of arrays. Other methods similar but usually more useful than the `forEach()` function include `map()`, `filter()`, `reduce()`, `find()`, `every()` and `some()`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - Hi, Niet before the question is closed, can you elaborate a bit more ... it was helpful but not completely clear to me. It would help. I could make out that -- these 5 are core loops, while others are functions that perform iteration, but nothing more than that. Pl, your elaboration would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we talk about the term "loop", we are talking about native language feature, which in most language is `break`able.

`.forEach()` on the other hand, is noticeablly un`break`able. It is a method of `Array` data type, it comes from the standard library of JS, part of EMCAScript spec, but is not part of JS the language itself. Internally its implementation rely on "loop" the feature.